# Change the select tag active / focus color after selection of options

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to customize a SELECT tag to match my website theme (black / dark)

I successfully matched all the colors but this annoying blue selection color ruined everything.

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something? I'm running this website on IE11, here's a code snippet of my work.

```css
select.anima {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    border: 0;
    background: black;
    height: 35px;
    width: 30%;
    color: white;
    padding: 2.5px;
}

select.anima::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
}

select.anima option:hover {
    background: #2B2B2B;
    color: white;
}

select.anima option:checked {
    background: #2B2B2B !important;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<select class="anima">
    <option>123</option>
    <option>qwe</option>
    <option>asd</option>
    <option>zxc</option>
</select>
```

Is it possible to override this thing? I'm just new in web-development, any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:focus` to your select tag which will solve the issue.

```css
select.anima {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    border: 0;
    background: black;
    height: 35px;
    width: 30%;
    color: white;
    padding: 2.5px;
}

select.anima::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
}

select.anima option:hover, select.anima option {
    background: #2B2B2B;
    color: white;
}

select.anima option:checked {
    background: #2B2B2B !important;
    color: white;
}

select.anima:focus{
    background: red !important;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<select class="anima">
    <option>123</option>
    <option>qwe</option>
    <option>asd</option>
    <option>zxc</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion but I already did this, it only changes the background color of the select tag. What i want to do is to change the blue highlight color on the selected option of the select tag (like what is shown on my question) using CSS only, if it is possible. And I am running this on IE11. :)

Comment: Hello @Chilll007 i am doing that thing with Multiple option selection. but its not working.